# Colunas das tabelas sql server não são reconhecidas no php

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho colunas que foram gravadas no sql server com letra maiúscula, quando recebo no php precisava que ele reconhecesse elas tanto minusculas quanto maiúsculas.

Por exemplo:

```
select * from rzv_aluno
```

registros:

```
AL_NOME, AL_EMPRESA... etc
```

no php só consigo ver os registros se eu apontar

```
$r->AL_NOME
```

gostaria que não houvesse diferença entre

```
$r->AL_NOME e $r->al_nome
```

Comment: Verifique o collation do banco de dados, provavelmente você está usando um collation case-sensitive. Você tem que mudar pra um collation case-insensitive pra usar do jeito que você quer, só não vou saber te dizer como muda no sql server.

Comment: No PHP o nome das variáveis são case-sensitive, mas o nome das funções não.